# Inject method in C# assembly with Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, .net, mono, mono.cecil

I'm developing some .Net application and I need to inject in any assembly new method with my own code. I'm using Mono.Cecil to get body of assembly and I found some samples, but they're old enough. Unfortunately, there's no info in migraton section on github wiki.

So, I have this code:

```
using System; 
using Mono.Cecil; 
using Mono.Cecil.Cil; 

namespace CustomFieldsInjection 
{ 
    public partial class Injector 
    { 
        public static void MethodInjection(string assemblyFilename, string typeName, string methodName) 
        { 
            AssemblyDefinition assembly = AssemblyFactory.GetAssembly(assemblyFilename); 

            TypeReference returnTypeReference = assembly.MainModule.Import(typeof(void)); 

            MethodDefinition methodDefinition = new MethodDefinition(methodName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, returnTypeReference); 

            Instruction instruction1 = methodDefinition.Body.CilWorker.Create(OpCodes.Nop); 

            Instruction instruction2 = methodDefinition.Body.CilWorker.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, methodName); 

            MethodReference writeline = assembly.MainModule.Import(typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) })); 

            methodDefinition.Body.CilWorker.Append(instruction1); 
            methodDefinition.Body.CilWorker.Append(instruction2); 

            methodDefinition.Body.CilWorker.InsertAfter(instruction2, methodDefinition.Body.CilWorker.Create (OpCodes.Call, writeline)); 

            methodDefinition.Body.CilWorker.Append (methodDefinition.Body.CilWorker.Create(OpCodes.Ret))

            assembly.MainModule.Inject(methodDefinition, assembly.MainModule.Types[typeName]); 
            MethodReference methodReference = null; 

            foreach (MethodDefinition method in assembly.MainModule.Types[typeName].Methods) 
            { 
                if (method.Name == methodName) 
                { 
                    methodReference = assembly.MainModule.Import(method); 
                    break; 
                } 
            } 

            Instruction callTest = methodDefinition.Body.CilWorker.Create(OpCodes.Call, methodReference); 

            if (assembly.EntryPoint != null) 
            { 
                assembly.EntryPoint.Body.CilWorker.InsertBefore(assembly.EntryPoint.Body.Instructions[0], callTest); 
            } 

            AssemblyFactory.SaveAssembly(assembly, assemblyFilename); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

It's old sample. Most features are up to date. I'm interesting in this construction:

```
assembly.MainModule.Inject(methodDefinition, assembly.MainModule.Types[typeName]);
```

I could not find a new analogues of this design. Someone can tell me what it can be replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the construct you are referring to, but adding a `MethodDefinition` to an existing type is quite easy

```cs
using (var assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("assemblyPath")) {
    var module = AssemblyDefinition.MainModule;

    //Select the type you need to open for addition
    var typeDef = module.Types.First(td => td.Name == "footer");

    //Add your MethodDefinition
    typeDef.Methods.Add(your_method_definition);

    //Write the assembly back
    assemblyDefinition.Write();
}
```

NOTE: If you don't use yet cecil 0.10.0.0 you'll use slightly different `ReadAssembly()` and `Write()` variants (without the `using`, and passing the assemblyPath to `Write`, mainly...)

Comment: @Stepane Delcroix Thanks a lot! It seems that this is what I need!

Comment: That doesn't work.  The Write() will throw a System.ArgumentException: 'Stream must be writable and seekable.'

Comment: @latency set the `readerParameters` of the `ReadAssembly` to include `ReadWrite = true`